# Access a global resource from cshtml

Tags: razor, resources, app-globalresources

I create a web app in visual studio 2012 and I also create a global resource file in order to use the same page in different languages.

I create a few key-value for each language I want and now Im trying to get that value from the cshtml.

I tried the following:

```
@Resources.Content.ES.UserInformation
```

where `Content.ES` is the name of the file and `UserInformation` is is the key.

When I wrote that line I have an error message saying that Resources doesnt exist.

Any help will be appreciate it!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was naming the resource as `@Resources.Content.ES.UserInformation` and the `.ES` was confusing it. So I changed it to `Content` and its all good now.